# USB-C monitor working with laptop and desktop?

Tags: laptop, display, desktop-computer, usb-c

At work I got a laptop, its nice. I simply plug in a USB-C cable and i got monitor, power, keyboard and mouse.

At home. I got a desktop computer.

Is it possible to create a setup where my keyboard, mouse and monitor can both be used by the dekstop and laptop? though not at the same time of course.

My desktop uses HDMI. I guess that is just a matter of the monitor using the HDMI or USB-C source. But what about the keyboard and mouse? I don't wan't to be swapping cables when working from home, I just wan't to plug in my USB-C as i do at work.

It seems you can get two way USB splitters. Two of those, one for keyboard and one for mouse where. For each splitter the left cable could go to the desktop computer and the right to the monitor for use by the laptop, over USB-C.

Would this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might or might not work, depending on too many variables to give an answer.

What you are really looking for is just one tool named
[KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch),
where KVM stands for "keyboard, video and mouse".
Many of them allow to switch between two computers using just a button.

As a random example (this isn't a recommendation), see
[this KVM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00J7JGAHM)
which seems to fulfill your needs, at $25.99.

There are many such KVM switches to be found on Amazon and elsewhere,
so search for the one that best fits your needs and constraints.

Comment: That KVM is VGA... (not HDMI)

Comment: Awesome thank you, never heard of it before but found some and its not to expensive either. I'll give it a shoot.

Comment: @Attie I've found a KVM switch thats just USB and can split into two outputs